# every method of angular service have same line of code for promise ($deferred)

Tags: angularjs, optimization

I am first time using angular JS so kindly bear my question. While creating service in angular JS  I have to write `var deferred = $q.defer();` and then `return deferred.promise;` in every method of service which use `$http()`

Is there any shorthand or alternative way to do so?

for eg:

```
(function() {

'use strict';    
angular
    .module('app')
    .service('AuthService', function($q, $http, $interval, $timeout, BASE_URL) {    
        var service = {
            login:  function(formdata) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.post(BASE_URL + '/api/getLogin', formdata).then(function(response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }, function(err) {
                            deferred.reject(err);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
            },
            signup:  function(formdata) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.post(BASE_URL + '/api/register', formdata).then(function(response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }, function(err) {
                            deferred.reject(err);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise; 
           },
           forgot: function(formdata) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http.post(BASE_URL + '/api/forgot', formdata).then(function(response) {
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        }, function(err) {
                            deferred.reject(err);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise; 
           }
        }

    return service;
```

});

here you can see I have to rewrite the same line of code in every method of service

Comment: $http.post() or get() is promise itself, just return $http.post(BASE_URL + '/api/getLogin', formdata);  and so on

Comment: also, check 'PromiseUtils' from my post in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888623/make-function-wait-for-http-response-in-angularjs/30888966#30888966   really helpful

Comment: `.success` and `.error` has been deprecated which you are using in autilpromise

Comment: that is not so useful for me as I am using `deferred.notify()` sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $http methods without any other code:

```
 return $http.post(BASE_URL + '/api/getLogin', formdata)
```

all $http methods return promise by default